# upload image using ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, file-upload

I have the following html form. Here the image upload is working fine. But i want to make the image upload in ajax so that before submitting the form with other details. The preview of the image can be shown in side.

```
<form action="<?=base_url();?>index.php/insert/insertdata" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <tr><td><b>Title: </b></td><td><input type="text" name="title"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td><b>Url: </b></td><td><input type="text" name="url"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td><b>Image: </b></td><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>

        <tr><td><b>Status: </b></td><td><select name="status"><option value="visible">Visible</option><option value="invisible">Invisible</option></select></td></tr>  

        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td><td><input type="reset" value="reset"/></td></tr>
    </form>
```

jquery is also welcome. But I would like to avoid using the form tag again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

once your uploading a image then fetch the image name with url and add to the

```
$.ajax(url,{data},function(res){

        //check status if it is 200 then assign the res to the img
       $('#img').attr('src',res);

})
```

//Html write this after the image file

```
 <img src="" id="img">
```

Comment: when I am uploading image my page is getting refreshed... I want to upload without page refresh.

Comment: `$target_path = "uploads/";

        $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
        {
                echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image']['name'])." has been uploaded";
        }
        else
        {
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }`

Answer (score 0):

If jquery is welcomed then there is no other better solution than [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). Use it and you will love it. Check also [demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/).

Comment: uplodify uses form tag and as I have described in my question "But I would like to avoid using the form tag again." I have image input tag in my form. So I cannot have an another form tag in a form tag.

Comment: who said you need to use another form? you can use the same form and thats all :-)

Comment: uploadify won't work. I don't want to use flash or html5. Further uploadify does not show the preview. This is not simply uploading the files. I want the name of the file to be stored in the database too.